# Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Boolean to Id at line 24 column 17 - Trigger create for line items

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger InsertPurchaseOrder on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {    
    Map<String, Id> poIdMapByVendorId = new Map<String, Id>();
    List<String> vendorIdList = new List<String>();
    Map<String, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c> poMapInserted = new Map<String, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c>();
    Map<String, List<AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c>> poLinesInsertedMapByVendorId = new Map<String, List<AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c>>(); 

    for (OpportunityLineItem oppLine : Trigger.new) {
        if (oppLine.VendorOrderId__c != null) {
            vendorIdList.add(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c);
        }       
    }
    if (!vendorIdList.isEmpty()){
        for (AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c po : [SELECT Id, Name, VendorId__c FROM AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c WHERE VendorId__c IN :vendorIdList]) {
            poIdMapByVendorId.put(po.VendorId__c, po.Id);
        }
    }
    vendorIdList.clear();
    Map<String, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c> poToBeInsertedMap = new Map<String, AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c>();
    Map<String, List<AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c>> poLinesToBeInsertedMapByVendorId = new Map<String, List<AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c>>(); 
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppLine : Trigger.New){
        if (oppLine.VendorOrderId__c != null) {
            if (poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c)) {
                AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c poLine = new AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c();
                poLine.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c);
                poLine.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);
                poLine.Quantity = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Quantity__c);
                poLine.UnitPrice = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Unit_Price__c);
                poLinesToBeInsertedMapByVendorId.add(poLine);
            } else {
                if (poToBeInsertedMap.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c)) {
                    AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c purchaseOrder = new AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c();
                    purchaseOrder.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c = poToBeInsertedMap.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c);
                    purchaseOrder.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = poToBeInsertedMap.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);
                    purchaseOrder.Quantity = poToBeInsertedMap.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Quantity__c);
                    purchaseOrder.UnitPrice = poToBeInsertedMap.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Unit_Price__c);
                    poLinesToBeInsertedMapByVendorId.add(purchaseOrder);
                } else {

                    AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c pos = new AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c();
                    pos.AcctSeedERP__Type__c = 'Standard';
                    pos.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Format__c = 'a0rC000000GJ3ef';
                    pos.AcctSeedERP__Order_Date__c = System.Today();
                    pos.AcctSeedERP__Status__c = 'Open';
                    poToBeInsertedMap.add(pos);

                    AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c poLines = new AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order_Line__c();
                    poLines.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c);
                    poLines.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);
                    poLines.Quantity = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Quantity__c);
                    poLines.UnitPrice = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Unit_Price__c);
                    poLinesToBeInsertedMapByVendorId.put(oppLine.id, poToBeInsertedMap);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this as boolean comparison where `poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);` returns either `true` or `false`

```
poLine.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);
```

Use this:

```
poLine.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = oppLine.Product2;
```

All these below lines should be rectified:

```
poLine.AcctSeedERP__Purchase_Order__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.VendorOrderId__c);
poLine.AcctSeedERP__Product__c = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.Product2);  

poLine.Quantity = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Quantity__c);
   poLine.UnitPrice = poIdMapByVendorId.containsKey(oppLine.AcctSeedERP__Unit_Price__c);
```

Comment: is it possible to change the trigger still it is throwing errors.

Comment: you have to change the trigger code to make it compile and workable

Comment: @Hi Santanu Boral, I have modified my trigger now It is working fine. Thanks..!!!